# How to read paper titles from science direct URL

Tags: html, xml, url, web-scraping

I want to extract only the paper titles published from particular Journal. To be very specific, I will give URL (https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/image-and-vision-computing/vol/93/). Now I want only the title of the paper. I did try paring the tree but failed to do so. Kindly help.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/image-and-vision-computing/vol/93/")
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
```

what to do next ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
    titles = tree.xpath('//span[@class="js-article-title"]')
    for title in titles:
        print(title.text)
```

Output:

```
Editorial Board
Transfer learning in computer vision tasks: Remember where you come from
FALF ConvNets: Fatuous auxiliary loss based filter-pruning for efficient deep CNNs
Out-of-region keypoint localization for 6D pose estimation
Region-based Fitting of Overlapping Ellipses and its application to cells segmentation
```

etc.